# When scanning for beacons is my phone Is my device discoverable?

Tags: mobile

When scanning for beacons with my mobile does my mobile then become discoverable (i.e. am I broadcasting my position) ?

Thanks in advance for your help.  John

Answer (score 0):

No: if your device is scanning for beacons, it does not broadcast as a beacon itself. But you need Bluetooth enabled to be able to detect beacons, so your phone will be discoverable through Bluetooth scan.

Cheers.

Comment: Tks Wojtek for your prompt and clear response.  Take care. John